# Mysql Get week of lifetime

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, week-number

`WEEK()` or `WEEKOFYEAR()` return week of the year. But if I want to `GROUP BY` week, with time range spanning over years, then the `GROUP BY WEEK()` wont work. Since WEEK will return same values for, lets say, January 3, 2010 and January 3, 2011. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself. `YEARWEEK();` function. Grouping by both the year and week won't solve the problem. As in that case, a week starting in December and ending in January will be split-ted to two due to group by year.

Answer (score 3):

Group by both week and year:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(column), WEEK(column)
```

Comment: it should be other way round

Comment: @Cris The order of `GROUP BY` conditions makes no difference to operation the only difference is aesthetic

Comment: @AeroX, thanks, I thought I learned something new. Apparently not.

Comment: Won't this split the week into two, which starts in december and ends in january?

Comment: @djaqeel: so long as the year is same, it won't split.

Comment: @djaqeel: `week('2013-12-31')` is `52`. But +1 day results a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select `YEAR` too in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT .... GROUP BY YEAR( date_field ), WEEKOFYEAR( date_field ), WEEK( date_field );
```

You can omit any of `WEEK...` conditions.